# HttpServletRequest & HttpServletResponse , how to access in a class library in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a class library project , in which i need to access session and cookies .
So I am trying to use like

```
public WebContext getContext(){
    WebContext ctx = null;
    ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
    return ctx;
}
```

But all i get is null in  `WebContextFactory.get()` this statement .
This class library is added to JSP project which invoke this method from a servlet. 
I am new to JAVA , so cannot think of much options.

Comment: probably it is thread related, i.e. the current thread has to be started by dwr for the webcontextfactory to return a value....

Comment: Can please tell what exactly i need to do to start thread by dwr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answear taken from [WebContextFactory.get() always returns null](http://git.net/ml/java.dwr.user/2007-10/msg00128.html)

> The problem is this when a request comes in for DWR, it's handled by the  dwr servlet/controller which sets the proper info inside the WebContext   to  use in that request (ThreadLocal as said below).  If you are accessing  WebContext outside a normal DWR request, the WebContext isn't setup for > that thread so it's empty.
>   There were a few messages in the forum about this same issue, but I don't  remember the details.  At any rate, you should try to use  the ServerContextFactory instead of the WebContextFactory if you're  going to access DWR from a non-DWR request.  It might be what you need.

See if this helps you get to bottom of the problem.

Comment: Ok I am checking for ServerContext

Comment: check this also, it provides more insight into DWR http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/threads.html